# Order Independent Hash in Java

Tags: java, hash, set, unordered

I'd like to calculate  a hash of a set of strings in Java. Yes I can sort the strings and calculate the
MD5 hash iterative using `digest.update`.
But I'd prefer to omit the sort and use something like `combineUnordered` https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained
There is a lot of similar question asking the same such as [Order-independant Hash Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734848/order-independant-hash-algorithm)
but non of them provides a simple example showing how to calculate iterative an order independent hash in Java.

Comment: Why do youneed to overwrite the hash algorithm of the set?

Comment: @SzigyártóMihály no need to overwrite, I'm looking for an simple example. I know MD5, which is order sensitive and MurmurHash which shouldn't, but I could not find an example of using it.

Comment: The set uses the sum of items' hashes, which is not depending on the order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just XOR each hash and the order wont matter, plus the hash size will be fixed rather than grow with the size of the collection.

**Hashcode using built in java string hashcode:**

```
int hashcode = strings.stream()
        .mapToInt(Object::hashCode)
        .reduce(0, (left, right) -> left ^ right);
```

**Hashcode using guava and MD5 like the question asked:**

```
Optional<byte[]> hash = strings.stream()
        .map(s -> Hashing.md5().hashString(s, Charset.defaultCharset()))
        .map(HashCode::asBytes)
        .reduce((left, right) -> xor(left, right));


static byte[] xor(byte[] left, byte[] right) {
    if(left.length != right.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    byte[] result = new byte[left.length];
    for(int i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (byte) (left[i] ^ right[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred method.  XORing the hashes is better than adding them.

Comment: Yes, this is true for *sets*, but for *bags* that can contains duplicates `XOR` is not applicable as the duplicates will reset it to *zero* @LukeJoshuaPark, so some `SUM` (wrapped) must be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the MD5 hash of each string individually, and then, add them all to get a single hash. That will be order independent. Because addition operation is commutative.

Here is an example (assuming we have a method **md5Hex(String str)** that calculates md5 hash for a given string and returns the results in hexadecimal format):

```
String[] strings = {"str1", "str2", "str3", ...};

BigInteger hashSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
for(String s : strings) {
    String hexHash = md5Hex(s);
    hashSum = hashSum.add(new BigInteger(hexHash, 16));
}

String finalHash = hashSum.toString(16);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you; the background of the question (though downwoted) was if I should go this way or use some alternative hash algorithm that can combine unsorted and possible receive less collisions.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Guava to calculate order-independent hash of a set of strings:

```
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.hash.HashCode;
import com.google.common.hash.HashFunction;
import com.google.common.hash.Hashing;

...

public String hash(final Set<String> strings) {
    final HashFunction function = Hashing.murmur3_128();

    // Hashing.combineUnordered will throw an exception if input is empty.
    if (strings.isEmpty()) {
        return function.newHasher()
            .hash()
            .toString();
    }

    final List<HashCode> stringsHashes = strings.stream()
            .map(string -> function.newHasher()
                    .putString(string, Charsets.UTF_8)
                    .hash())
            .toList();

    return Hashing.combineUnordered(stringsHashes).toString();
}
```